# Get the country list in alphabetic order in 2 columns

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the country list in 2 columns.

My current CSS makes the list display one after the other as below:

```
+-----------------------------------+
Global  | Argentina      | Australia
+-----------------------------------+
Austria | Czech Republic | Denmark
+-----------------------------------+
```

But I want my country to be displayed as below without changing the HTML `ul` & `li`

```
+-------------------------+
Global    | Czech Republic
+-------------------------+
Argentina | Denmark
+-------------------------+
Australia
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="CountryList">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="/english">Global</a></li>
       <!-- More li elements -->
   </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.CountryList ul
{
list-style:none;
}

.CountryList ul li {
width: 25%;
margin: .5em 2%;
float:left;
}
```

Is there any CSS solution to get this done ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not willing to change the DOM, than you will have to use [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count) property

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d8DFz/)

```
.CountryList {
    -moz-column-count: 10;
    -webkit-column-count: 10;
    column-count: 10;
    height: 100px;
    -moz-column-gap: 100px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 100px;
    column-gap: 100px;
}
```

---

As far as the support goes, you can refer it [here](http://caniuse.com/multicolumn), so if you are willing to leave vintage browsers than its fine, else consider changing the DOM else use JavaScript or jQuery to achieve that.